# When modules written in different languages interact, is exchanged data always serialized?

Tags: python, data, memory

I have module written in Python and I would like to write function in e.g. Go but problem is that data needed for computations is often more than 100MB. My question is: is data always serialized and send to other module (causing to duplicate data in memory) or under the hood there is a mechanism to read data from Python process memory? Also, how does it look with different technologies like Rust, C++ etc.?

Comment: In the Apple dev environment Carbon and Cocoa implementations of some objects were binary compatible. All the programmer in C/C++/Objective-C had to do was cast the pointer. Also there is a powerful mechanism called memory mapping, there is doubtlessly a way to memory map a region to be accessible from within and without python, even across process boundaries. But this does necessitate a closeness between the two programs, which is not always desirable.

Comment: @Kain0_0 yup but for data processing (big data etc.) this is not a problem, thanks for great remark

Answer (score 3):

It is generally serialized because serialization is the lowest common denominator, thus it is the easiest thing to code to and verify.

When this becomes a limitation, you can look at your specific problem and see if there is a better solution.  For example, if the large data objects in Python are actually numpy arrays, numpy exposes its internals with a C API.  So you could unpack the Python layer manually and then use the numpy C API to access the raw data in the buffer, avoiding all of those copies.

This approach is almost always tied to the specific problem because crossing language boundaries is exceedingly difficult in the general case.  Issues such as memory management get really interesting and difficult.

As a case study, trying to weave Java and C# together can be tricky because both rely on a cycle-detecting garbage collector, but neither can see into the other's memory, so any data going across that boundary must be managed with refcounts without cycle detection.  Even trying to weave together two different Java engines with different garbage collectors can have this issue, despite being the same language with the same guarantees.

Comment: Actually, CPython (the Python implementation most often used) has a sophisticated buffer mechanism which underlies the numpy C interface. Interchanging (binary) data using that mechanism is pretty powerful.